# jQuery image import to Crystal Report

Tags: html, jquery, crystal-reports

I am trying to find a way how to import image from html to Crystal Reports. What I found is I need to set a code to download and save the image to a database and then add it to Crystal Report.

In other words, I need to find a way to add image dynamically to the Crystal Reports from HTML using id, rather than save it to a database.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean save the HTML page as an image and display the result in Crystal?  There is a User Function Library (UFL) that provides that functionality. See list of UFLs [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl).

If you mean an image file referenced by an HTML page, then it's just a file (the fact that it is also used in an HTML page is irrelevant.  You can simply use the path to that file.

Consider providing more details...